# limitation of the reception buffer

Tags: sockets, networking, erlang, erlang-otp

I established a connection with a client this way:

```
gen_tcp:listen(1234,[binary,{packet,0},{reuseaddr,true},{active,false},{recbuf,2048}]).
```

This code performs message processing:

```
loop(Socket)->
    inet:setops(Socket,[{active,once}],
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Data}->
            handle(Data),
            loop(Socket);
        {Pid,Cmd}->
            gen_tcp:send(Socket,Cmd),
            loop(Socket);
        {tcp_close,Socket}->
            % ...
end.
```

My OS is Windows. When the size of the message is 1024 bytes, I lose bytes in `Data`. The server sends ACK + FIN to the client.

I believe that the Erlang is limited to 1024 bytes, therefore I defined `recbuf`.

Where the problem is: Erlang, Windows, hardware?

Thanks.

Comment: Really no idea of the problem ?

Comment: I'm not an Erlang guy, so can't really understand what you are doing. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be setting the receive buffer far too small. Erlang certainly isn't limited to a 1024 byte buffer. You can check for yourself by doing the following in the shell:

```
{ok, S} = gen_tcp:connect("www.google.com", 80, [{active,false}]),
O = inet:getopts(S, [recbuf]),
gen_tcp:close(S),
O.
```

On Mac OS X I get a default receive buffer size of about 512Kb.

---

With `{packet, 0}` parsing, you'll receive tcp data in whatever chunks the network stack chooses to send it in, so you have to do message boundary parsing and buffering yourself. Do you have a reliable way to check message boundaries in the wire protocol? If so, receive the tcp data and append it to a buffer variable until you have a complete message. Then call handle on the complete message and remove the complete message from the buffer before continuing.

We could probably help you more if you gave us some information on the client and the protocol in use.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. unfortunately I don't have any information (I try the reverse engeenering method). the client send one or several messages separated by <cr><lf>. the problem is the "several" ! therefore I have no criteria to finish the buffering.

Comment: So you have a message boundary marker of '\r\n'? If so, then Erlang has the solution built in - use `{packet, line}` in the listen options to get Erlang to buffer entire lines for you. Then process as many line messages from the socket as you need to, or process until you get a socket closed message.