# Erlang get_tcp:recv data length

Tags: sockets, erlang

I user `gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0).` for data receiveng, but i can receive only 1418 bytes for 1 time. How can I receive how much data was sent?

Comment: This question may be helpful: [Limitation of the reception buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4797060/298282).

Comment: I vote to close the question, as similar questions appear once a fortnight.

Comment: It is slightly different though in this case, note that. Even if they do come up now and again.

Answer (score 8):

in `gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0)` you are asking the kernel: "Give me all data there is available right now in the receive buffer". The kernel is also free to give you less however. Even for a rather fast link, you will probably hit *slow start* on the TCP connection so in the beginning you will not get much data.

The solution is to do your own buffering. You will have to eat data from the underlying socket until you have enough to construct a message. It is quite common for binary protocols to implement their own kind of messaging on top of the stream due to this.

---

For the longer term record: A common message format is to encode a message as:

```
decode(Bin) when is_binary(Bin) ->
  <<Len:32/integer, R/binary>> = Bin,
  <<Payload:Len/binary, Remain/binary>>,
  {msg, {Len, Payload}, Remaining}.
```

That is, messages are 4 bytes representing a 32-bit bigendian integer followed by the payload, where the length is given by the integer. This format, and others like it, are so common Erlang includes optimized parsers for it directly in the C-layer. To get access to these, you set options on the socket through `inet/setops/2`, in our case we set `{packet, 4}`. Then we can get messages by setting `{active, once}` on the socket and wait for the next message. When it arrives, we can `{active, once}` again on the socket to get the next message, and so on. There is an example in the documentation of `gen_tcp` (`erl -man gen_tcp` if you have the Erlang man-pages installed appropriately).

Other common formats are asn.1 or even http headers(!).

#### Tricks

It is often beneficial to create a process which is separate that can encode and decode your message format and then send on data to the rest of the system. Usually a good solution in Erlang is to demux incoming data as fast as possible and get the data to a process which can then handle the rest of the problem.

Comment: Good answer, the problem why these questions keep to appear is that TCP is misinterpreted as a message based protocol.  If looking at it as reliable serial line it gets much clearer.

Comment: I tend to agree. Also note that SCTP is probably the right protocol to use for messages, but nobody seems to care about it, sadly :/