# Erlang gen_tcp and line i/o

Tags: erlang

Is there any way to read whole lines from a socket in Erlang, or do I need to implement line buffering manually on top of `gen_tcp:recv`?

Comment: I think it will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081298/erlang-get-tcprecv-data-length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
inet:setopts(Socket, [{packet, line}])
```

See: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#setopts-2

Cheers!

Comment: I'd also say {active, once} in those options if you only want one line. But yeah - this is a good approach if you don't want to manage buffering yourself.

Comment: @archaelus uhmm...with {active, once} you wouldn't call gen_tcp:recv, but receive the lines as messages.. in this case inet:setopts/2 works for both scenarios (each call to gen_tcp:recv will return 1 line), but using {active, once} has nothing to do with setting {packet, line} or others, just with how you would want read (get) that line from the Socket

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement line buffering yourself.

`gen_tcp:listen/2` accepts `{packet, line}` for its `Options` argument, which will put the socket into line mode and so calls to `gen_tcp:recv` will block until a complete line has been read.

```
gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{packet, line}])
```

Make sure that your buffer size set via the `{buffer, Size}` option to the same call (or `inet:setopts/2`) is big enough that it will fit all of your lines, otherwise they will be truncated.

Or, if using Elixir, this should get you started:

```
:gen_tcp.listen(port, [packet: :line, buffer: 1024])
```